Can power of three have a lot of leading 9
I came up with this problem, but was unable to either prove or disprove the statement.
Let $dig(n)$ be the number of digits in the decimal representation of $n$. Is it true that $dig(3^n+2^n)=dig(3^n)$ when $n \geq 3$ is a natural number?
Of course, $\frac{dig(3^n)}{dig(2^n)}=\frac{ln(3)}{ln(2)}$ approximately, which is around $1.5$. So in order that to happen $3^n$ should have a lot leading nines, namely around $1-\frac{ln(2)}{ln(3)}$ percent of all digits, which is around $37$ percent. One possible approach is to consider log base 10 of $3^n$, but it didn't really lead me to anything vital. To be precize, in order for $3^n$ to start with $k$ nines, $nlog_{10} 3$ mod $1$ should be in the range $[log_{10} (10^k-1)$ mod $1,1)$. The length of it is $l=log_{10}(\frac{10^k}{10^k-1})$, then $\frac{1}{l}=log_{1+\frac{1}{10^k-1}}(10)$, which is approximately $ln(10)10^k$. Then by Diophantine's theorem there exists an $n \leq ln(10)10^k$ such that $3^n$ starts with $k$ nines. But in this estimation $k$ is asymptoticly $log_{10}(n)$, however we need a constant multiplied by $n$. 
Unfortunately, that was the only idea that popped into my mind.

Here you are assuming $n$ is a natural number, correct?

Of course! Otherwise the definition of $dig$ function would have zero sense

Add some elements to your post as otherwise it may be closed soon. Have you made  some  numerical tests ? Why is this question interesting ? Just curiosity ?

@RyszardSzwarc It's a good question because you will need a lot of 9's at the beginning of the number as $n$ grows the disparity in power of $3^x$ and $3^n$ is immense. It makes it so that if there is a counterexample it would be fairly small, so long as you can prove that $3^n$ doesn't start with too many 9's. But it's somewhat difficult maybe but still a valid logical question about number theory, no?

@Snared I also find this question interesting. But some analysis should be included into the post, as it already has got one close vote.

@Snared Since $\log_{10}3$ is an irrational number the sequence $n\log_{10}3$ $\mod , 1$ is dense in $(0,1).$ Hence for any $k$ there is $n$ such that the number $3^n$ starts with $k$ digits equal $9.$ Still $3^n(1+(2/3)^n)$ and $3^n$ may have the same number of digits. The relation between $n$ and $k$ is crucial.

Perhaps some measure theoretic methods can be used, as the sequence $n\log 3$ $\mod ,1$ is equidisdributed in $(0,1),$ if I remember well.

FWIW, values of $n$ with $\log_{10} 3^n$ very close to (within $10^{-7}$ of) an integer include: 6292019, 8611071, 12584038, 14903090, 21195109, 27487128, 33779147, 36098199, 42390218, 48682237, 54974256, 57293308, 63585327, 69877346, 76169365, 78488417, 84780436, 91072455, 97364474, 99683526.

The connection between $\mathrm{dig}(2^n+3^n)=\mathrm{dig}(3^n)$ and the question posed is not clear as stated. It would appear that if this equation is not true for some $n$, then $3^n$ should start with a large number of $9$'s.For example $3^n+2^n$ and $3^n$ have the same number of digits for $n=3,4,5$. So it is the failure of this equation that is rare.

@RyszardSzwarc just for the record, this seems like a perfectly acceptable question to me, as is, and identical in form and paradigm to most of the questions on here - ?

@Fattie I have the same opinion. I was worried that the question would be closed, that's why I asked for more details. For no reason, in my opinion, there are 3 close votes by now, none of them from me.

@RyszardSzwarc - understood !

This would follow from a sufficiently strong form of the abc conjecture. Write $3^n + b = 10^k$ where $k = \text{dig}(3^n)$. The abc conjecture implies that for any $\varepsilon > 0$, $10^k$ must eventually be bounded by a constant times $(30b)^{1 + \varepsilon}$, which means that $b$ must eventually be at least a constant times $10^{\frac{k}{1 + \varepsilon}}$. So, up to finitely many counterexamples, the fraction of leading nines can't be more than $\varepsilon$ for any $\varepsilon > 0$. Picking, say, $\varepsilon = 0.1$ would suffice here. A sufficiently strong version of the abc conjecture (with sufficiently good bounds on the constants) could then bound how large the counterexamples can be, and then we could rule them out by explicit calculation.
